# Not getting zipcode from Latitude and Longitude

Tags: android, android-location

I am trying to find out the latitude and longitude in an Android application. The code that I am using is as follows:-

```
protected int findZipCode() {

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener listener = new MyLocationListener();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 60000,
            1000, listener);
    if (zipCode == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return Integer.parseInt(zipCode);
    }
}

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (location != null) {
            Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
            List<Address> addr = null;
            try {
                addr = geo.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),
                        location.getLatitude(), 5);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            zipCode = addr.get(0).getPostalCode();
        }
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

But this code seems to always return a null value for the zipcode. Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

As your `MyLocationListener`  is running in parallel at that point your zipCode is null therefore you are getting 0 value.

**Fix**

You can wait the `MyLocationListener` to complete and pass a `interface` method to this `listener` and on the complete of this function you can call that method.

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing dude?

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 60000,1000, listener);
```

The above line is a asynchronus call, listener will be called when you get a position fix. 
You can't check for zipcode right after this line. 
In listner when you get the value of zipcode, implement some interface/callback which will give you the value of zipcode in your activity or where ever you want.

Comment: Can you plz suggest the tweaks that I need to make in my code??

Comment: findZipCodeFunction is written where? and where is Listner defined? in same activity?

Comment: Yeah they both are in the same activity... I need the person to get the zipcode and then I am performing a search on the basis of zipcode in my app...

Comment: well, its not that hard in this case.. just remove the if else statment from findZipCode.. then lets say, when you get zipcode, you call function: func()... so call this func() right in listner where you are getting zipcode from getPostalCode();